# Pointer to nth element in a vector of list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector

I need to return a pointer to some value in my list

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> lists;
...
if(lists.at(i).front()==val){
   //return a pointer after the first value
   return ptr;
}
```

The best way i can think of is using `std::next`, but i have no idea how to make it returns a pointer

Comment: Are you aware of `&`, aka the address operator?

Comment: I think might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you want to return a pointer to an element of a vector of lists? Why don't you use iterators and just increment `begin()`?

Comment: By the way, lists don't have fast random access. This means that it takes linear time to access some random element.

Comment: `&(*(std::next(lists.at.(i).begin(), 1)))`.   The `*` converts an iterator to a reference, and `&` obtains the address of what the reference refers to.

Comment: Why do you need a pointer instead of an iterator?

Answer (score 0):

> The best way i can think of is using `std::next`, but i have no idea how to make it returns a pointer

`std::next` returns an iterator. You can use the indirection operator to get the pointed object. You can use the addressof operator to get the memory address (i.e. a pointer) of that object. So:

```
auto it = whatever; // iterator to the object whose pointer you want
return &*it;        // return the pointer
```

---

Not relevant to `int`, but for some rare cases, you may need to use `std::addressof` in case the the type has an overloaded addressof operator.

Also, I recommend considering whether it makes any sense to return a pointer rather than the iterator itself.

Comment: Why `std::next`? Why not just `data_type* ptr = &lists.at(i).front()`?

Comment: @zindarod that returns a pointer to the first element. john said he wants pointer to [an object, I assume] *after* the first value. `std::next` can be used to get an element after the first.

Comment: `ptr++` will give him the next value though, won't it?

Comment: @zindarod no, it won't. `std::list` is not an array. (Sorry, I said yes first since I misread your question)

Comment: Ah, so objects in the list don't have consecutive memory addresses.

Comment: @zindarod Exactly. And that's one of the reasons why I suggest john to consider whether returning the iterator would make more sense (it probably does).

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are just "better" pointers. That is, you can use them as pointers (access value by dereferencing them)

```
auto it = lists.at(i).begin() // returns iterator to first element in i-th list in vector
...
*it // you can access value as if "it" was pointer
it++; // iterators can be "moved", that is, they will point to next element than before
```

if you really wish to return pointer type `*int`, instead of `std::list<int>::iterator`, you dereference it and gain reference back again

```
return &(*it);
```

for more on iterators, you can look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). You can see that there are many types of iterators, but all can be dereference as if they were pointers.

std::list<>:iterator is bidirectional iterator (they don't have random access, but you can move them by one element at a time, forward or backward)

Comment: The `std::list` iterator is not only a forward iterator, but more specifically a bidirectional iterator.

Comment: good point, thanks. Didn't even know that lists are doubly linked

Answer (score 0):

I think of a function like this:

```
std::list<int>::iterator get(std::vector<std::list<int>>& lists, int i,int val)
{
   assert(i<lists.size());

   if(lists.at(i).front()==val)
    {
       //return a pointer after the first value
       std::list<int>::iterator it = lists.at(i).begin();
      return it++;
   } 
    return lists.at(i).end();
}
```